# Using columns values dynamically based on the type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to identify a column based on the type.
In below sample data if the type is 1 then the next value field is of name and if 2 then those are address fields.
It is not mandatory all fields will be there for all consumers.
like for consumer 101 only type1 and type2 are name fields but for consumers 100 type1 type2 and type3 are name fields.
Name fields can be lastname, firstname and middle name
Address fields can be addressline1, addressline2 and addressline3

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Sample input and expected output queries below:

```
DECLARE @CONSUMER TABLE(
    ConsumerID VARCHAR(20),
    Type1 VARCHAR(1),
    Value1  VARCHAR(100),
    Type2 VARCHAR(1),
    Value2  VARCHAR(100),
    Type3 VARCHAR(1),
    Value3  VARCHAR(100),
    Type4 VARCHAR(1),
    Value4  VARCHAR(100),
    Type5 VARCHAR(1),
    Value5  VARCHAR(100),
    Type6 VARCHAR(1),
    Value6  VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO @CONSUMER
SELECT '100','1','John','1','Smith','1','M','2','test line1','2','test line2','2','test line3' UNION ALL
SELECT '101','1','John','1','Smith','2','line1','2','line2','2','line3','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '104','1','John','1','Smith','2','test line1','','','','','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '105','1','John','2','test line1','','','','','','','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '106','1','John','1','Smith','2','test line1','2','test line2','','','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '102','1','John','2','test line1','2','test line2','2','test line3','','','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '103','1','John','1','Smith','1','M','2','test line1','2','test line2','',''

--SELECT *FROM @CONSUMER

--EXPECTED OUTPUT
SELECT '100' ConsmerID,'John' LastName,'Smith' FirstName,'M' MiddleName,'test line1' AddressLine1,'test line2' AddressLine2,'test line3' AddressLine3 UNION ALL
SELECT '101','John','Smith','','line1','line2','line3' UNION ALL
SELECT '104','John','Smith','','test line1','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '105','john','','','test line1','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '106','John','Smith','','test line1','test line2','' UNION ALL
SELECT '102','John','','','test line1','test line2','test line3' UNION ALL
SELECT '103','John','Smith','M','test line1','test line2',''
```

I have tried different ways of doing but it is getting complicated.
Expecting a similar method of achieving this.

Comment: This doesn't read like a question, but like your treating [so] as a free coding service (the fact your refered to the **volunteers** as a "*team*" doesn't help that image). You've stated what you *want* but not what you're asking. [so] is a Q&A site, not a free coding service; please don't treat it like the latter. As a user for ~2 years, you really should have taken the time to read the [tour] by now; you were prompted to when you signed up but you're yet to do so.

Comment: simply select all columns that you need and add a alias to every column

Comment: @eshwar, `there's no I in team`. This looks nothing more than unpivot / pivot combo, you should include your tries too

Comment: Generally I don’t post questions in here.. because of the arrogant responses.. last question I posted here is few years back

Answer (score 1):

This is a unpivot/pivot dressed in fancy clothes:

```sql
DECLARE @CONSUMER TABLE(
    ConsumerID VARCHAR(20),
    Type1 VARCHAR(1),
    Value1  VARCHAR(100),
    Type2 VARCHAR(1),
    Value2  VARCHAR(100),
    Type3 VARCHAR(1),
    Value3  VARCHAR(100),
    Type4 VARCHAR(1),
    Value4  VARCHAR(100),
    Type5 VARCHAR(1),
    Value5  VARCHAR(100),
    Type6 VARCHAR(1),
    Value6  VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO @CONSUMER
SELECT '100','1','John','1','Smith','1','M','2','test line1','2','test line2','2','test line3' UNION ALL
SELECT '101','1','John','1','Smith','2','line1','2','line2','2','line3','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '104','1','John','1','Smith','2','test line1','','','','','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '105','1','John','2','test line1','','','','','','','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '106','1','John','1','Smith','2','test line1','2','test line2','','','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '102','1','John','2','test line1','2','test line2','2','test line3','','','','' UNION ALL
SELECT '103','1','John','1','Smith','1','M','2','test line1','2','test line2','',''


SELECT  consumerID
,   max(case when t = 1 and newsort = 1 then v end) as LastName
,   max(case when t = 1 and newsort = 2 then v end) AS FirstName
,   max(case when t = 1 and newsort = 3 then v end) AS MiddleName
,   max(case when t = 2 and newsort = 1 then v end) AS Line1
,   max(case when t = 2 and newsort = 2 then v end) AS Line2
,   max(case when t = 2 and newsort = 3 then v end) AS Line3
FROM (
    select  consumerID
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by consumerid, t order by sort) as newSort
    ,   t, v
    from @Consumer
    CROSS APPLY (
        values  (type1, value1, 1)
        ,   (type2, value2, 2)
        ,   (type3, value3, 3)
        ,   (type4, value4, 4)
        ,   (type5, value5, 5)
        ,   (type6, value6, 6)
        ) x (t, v, sort)
    WHERE x.t <> ''
    ) x
group by consumerID
```

- First you unpivot your data by doing a VALUES CROSS APPLY. This generates new row for every column / type combination
- Then you remove empty rows `WHERE x.t <> ''`
- Then, you recalculate the order of the values partitioned by the type of value, ie. name vs address: `ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by consumerid, t order by sort) as newSort`
- Finally, you create a pivot by doing the conditional aggregation in form of `max(case when t = 1 and newsort = 1 then v end)`, this lets you create column for your desired output.

Results:

| consumerID | LastName | FirstName | MiddleName | Line1 | Line2 | Line3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | John | Smith | M | test line1 | test line2 | test line3 |
| 101 | John | Smith | NULL | line1 | line2 | line3 |
| 102 | John | NULL | NULL | test line1 | test line2 | test line3 |
| 103 | John | Smith | M | test line1 | test line2 | NULL |
| 104 | John | Smith | NULL | test line1 | NULL | NULL |
| 105 | John | NULL | NULL | test line1 | NULL | NULL |
| 106 | John | Smith | NULL | test line1 | test line2 | NULL |

Comment: Thanks this helps